# Xamarin MotionEventActions.Move never gets hit in custom views onTouch event?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an app where I am drawing lines through points to form polygons, I want to be able to have the four corners of the polygon be moveable, I have this code inside of a custom view I've created for drawing polygons:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
        MotionEventActions action = e.Action;

        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        float radius = 20.0f;

        // Get the current pointer index
        int tempPointerIndex = e.ActionIndex;
        x = e.GetX(tempPointerIndex);
        y = e.GetY(tempPointerIndex);

        // For each point, check to see if the touch fell within the bounds of the circle
        for (int i = 0; i < _points.Length; i++)
        {
            if((x >= _points[i].X - radius && x <= _points[i].X + 20) || 
               (y >= _points[i].Y - radius && y >= _points[i].Y + 20))
            {
                switch (action)
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    {


                        // Get the current x/y when not moving so we can calculate the delta x/y in 
                        // move events
                        lastX = x;
                        lastY = y;

                        // Set the global active pointer index
                        activePointerId = e.GetPointerId(0);

                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    {

                            int pointerIndex = e.FindPointerIndex(activePointerId);
                            x = e.GetX(pointerIndex);
                            y = e.GetY(pointerIndex);

                            // Find the delta x/y
                            float deltaX = x - lastX;
                            float deltaY = y - lastY;

                            // Move the selected skew handle by the delta x/y
                            _points[i].X += deltaX;
                            _points[i].Y += deltaY;

                            // Force a redraw
                            this.Invalidate();

                            break;
                    }
                    case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    {
                        // Invalidate the active pointer index
                        activePointerId = global::Android.Views.MotionEvent.InvalidPointerId;
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    {
                        // Invalidate the active pointer index
                        activePointerId = global::Android.Views.MotionEvent.InvalidPointerId;
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                    {
                            int pointerIndex = e.ActionIndex;
                            int pointerId = e.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);

                            if(pointerId == activePointerId)
                            {
                                // Active pointer going up, choose new active pointer and adjust accordingly
                                int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                                lastX = e.GetX(newPointerIndex);
                                lastY = e.GetY(newPointerIndex);
                                activePointerId = e.GetPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                            }

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

The case for `MotionEventActions.Move` never seems to get hit, in fact, the only event that seems to get hit is the down event when I initially hit a point. Also, the condition that checks the bounds of the point works for sure, I've tested it numerous times, so that isn't the issue either, I'm not sure if maybe I'm checking for the event incorrectly, but as far as I can tell this is how both the Xamarin and Android documentation say to handle this event, so I'm not really sure what the problem is, or how to find it. My question is, what exactly am I doing wrong that is causing the move event to not be picked up?

Comment: Your `MotionEventActions.Move` code is within a `for` loop and `if` statement for an X/Y that is moving AFTER the `MotionEventActions.Down` starts. You need to move `Move` and `Up` outside of your `Down` logic checks

Comment: @SushiHangover As in do those checks before the down check, or do those checks in a separate switch, or what? I don't see why that would help, I'm not doubting you, just the way I'm understanding what you're saying doesn't make any sense to me as to why that would fix the issue.

Comment: To be clear, I see what you are saying, and that's a valid point, but it doesn't have anything to do with my real issue, the move case never gets hit at all, it doesn't register movement in the view it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you determine if one of your points is in range of the user's touch, start returning  `true` from `OnTouchEvent` until you get an `Up`, that way all future touch events become `Move` events on your custom `View` and are not redirected to the View's parent.

#### Down/Move/Up touch event logic:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    x = e.GetX(e.ActionIndex);
    y = e.GetY(e.ActionIndex);
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"{e.Action} : {x} : {y}" );
    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        if (true) // some check if the x/y touch is on or near a moveable point, isDraggingPoint becomes true
            isDraggingPoint = true;
        else 
            isDraggingPoint = false;
    }
    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
    {
        // move your Point, x/y touch for draggingPoint, update display, etc... 
    }
    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
    {
        // save the final x/y touch for draggingPoint, update display, etc... 
        isDraggingPoint = false;
    }
    return isDraggingPoint;
}
```

#### Output:

```
[CustomView] Down : 358.5332 : 234.6167
[CustomView] Move : 358.5332 : 234.6167
[CustomView] Move : 352.5305 : 238.6241
[CustomView] Move : 334.8269 : 237.3517
[CustomView] Move : 360.5305 : 246.6073
[CustomView] Move : 360.5305 : 246.6073
[CustomView] Up : 360.5305 : 246.6073
```

Comment: I just had noticed that I wasn't returning true, and it indeed did fix the problem, I was just about to post here, accepted, thank you.